# Xpath contains attribute A with string X or Y and contains attribute B with string Z

Tags: xml, xpath, contains

Here is the XML structure

```
<Row type='apple' price='1' quantity='6' date='2013-06-08' transactiontype='sell'/>
<Row type='apple' price='1.5' quantity='3' date='2013-06-07' transactiontype='buy'/>
<Row type='apple' price='1.4' quantity='2' date='2013-06-05' transactiontype='buy'/>
<Row type='orange' price='4' quantity='5' date='2013-06-05' transactiontype='sell'/>
```

My current query is

```
//row[@type='apple' and @transactiontype='buy']/attribute::price
```

But this query doesn't allow me to select the date range. If I wanted to allow for all transaction dates between 2013-06-06 and 2013-06-08, how would I edit my query?

Comment: `and (@date >= '2013-06-06' and @date <= '2013-06-08')`?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no notion of a date type in XPath 1.0 (which I assume you are using), you must convert the date strings to numbers (strings cannot be compared with <, <=, > or =>). You can either write the date values as `20130608` directly in your XML, or use the `translate` function to remove the dashes in the comparison.

A working XPath expression for the second option could look like so:

```
//Row[@type='apple' and @transactiontype='buy' and 
  (translate(@date, '-', '') >= 20130606 and 
   translate(@date, '-', '') <= 20130608)]/attribute::price
```

Comment: I would simply put the literals in there as number literals i.e. `/Row[@type='apple' and @transactiontype='buy' and 
  (translate(@date, '-', '') >= 20130606 and 
   translate(@date, '-', '') <= 20130608)]/attribute::price`, there is no need to use string literals only to have them converted to numbers by the `<=` respectively `>=` operator.